# How to add date & time with another date & time in a same column

Tags: mysql

i have table like below. I want to add the time difference from the same column.

mysql> show create table table_name;

table_name | CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
`s_no` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`heading` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date_with_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`s_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=597 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

| heading | date with time |
| --- | --- |
| inactive | 7/6/2021 09:59:00 AM |
| **active** | **7/6/2021 10:00:00 AM** |
| inactive | 7/6/2021 10:29:00 AM |
| **active** | **7/6/2021 10:30:00 AM** |
| inactive | 7/6/2021 12:59:00 PM |
| **active** | **7/6/2021 01:00:00 PM** |
| inactive | 7/6/2021 01:29:00 PM |
| **active** | **7/6/2021 01:30:00 PM** |

From the above i just want to know only active time.

| heading | date with time |
| --- | --- |
| Total | 210 min |

Comment: I think in your example, you mean `active -> inactive, active -> inactive` ?

Comment: yes, but here i just want calculate only active time. total active time in a day is 60 mins.

Comment: as per above table my total active time should be 210mins.

Comment: Firstly, run this query > `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` and post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68266890/edit). Secondly, according to your data table sample above, how to identify the start time and the end time or a cycle?

Comment: FaNo_FN details updated. please check